# How to add custom fields to user types in Rails with Devise and STI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, device, sti

I am trying to define the models based on the following diagram

[image: UML diagram]

My problem occurs when trying to generate a migration for the "Teacher" type, how can I add a custom field (like salary) to each of my user types if I can't create a migration because they are not a table as such.

I already have a model created with Devise for User, but I cannot find documentation or related examples for this type of case with custom fields for User types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*STI* stands for *single table inheritence*. This means when you want to add a column to one of the subtypes then you need to add that column to the superclasses table.

In your example, when you want a `Teacher#salary` attribute then you need to add that `salary` column to the `users` table.

This means you will need a have a migration like this:

```
class AddSalaryToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :salary, :decimal, precision: 8, scale: 2
  end
end
```

You might want to read about STI in the [Rails API docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) and follow the link to [Martin Fowler: Single Table Inheritance](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html).